# Testing JQuery's "on" method fires callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am trying to test following code with Jasmine:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export function createCheckIcon (handleClick) {
  return $('<span>').attr('data-element', 'check').addClass('icon--check').on('click', handleClick);
}

export function createCrossIcon (handleClick) {
  return $('<span>').attr('data-element', 'cross').addClass('icon--cross').on('click', handleClick);
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

import { createCrossIcon, createCheckIcon } from './input-icons';

describe('input icons', () => {

  let handleMock = { handleClick: () => true };

  it('can create a cross icon', () => {
    let $crossIcon = createCrossIcon();
    expect($crossIcon).toHaveAttr('data-element', 'cross');
    expect($crossIcon).toHaveClass('icon--cross');
  });

  it('cross icon handles click event', () => {
    let $crossIcon = createCrossIcon(handleMock.handleClick);
    spyOn(handleMock, 'handleClick');
    $crossIcon.trigger('click');
    expect(handleMock.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('can create a check icon', () => {
    let $checkIcon = createCheckIcon();
    expect($checkIcon).toHaveAttr('data-element', 'check');
    expect($checkIcon).toHaveClass('icon--check');
  });
});
```

Unfortunately my test will fail with:

```
Expected spy handleClick to have been called.
```

Maybe I still have a basic misunderstanding how to test if the click handle was fired. Does anyone see where my problem is? I also tried jasmine-jquery to get this working but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

You have a misconception of how variables work in JavaScript.

You see, when you pass `handleClick` in `createCrossIcon(handleMock.handleClick)`
you are actually passing a link to the function, not the function itself. And then you pass this link to the `.on` method.

Then you set a Jasmine spy - `spyOn(handleMock, 'handleClick')` and what happens is Jasmine replaces the `handleClick` property of `handleMock` object with a utility function that remembers all the times it was called.

But jQuery will never know about your intentions, because it has already decided to call the original function on click.

### The solution

What you need to do is simply change the order of the lines so that `spyOn` will come **before** creating an icon:

```
spyOn(handleMock, 'handleClick');
let $crossIcon = createCrossIcon(handleMock.handleClick);
```

This way you will pass a spy as a callback, not the actual callback function.

Comment: Wow! Nice. Thank you very much. You are right. It is working.